# addAnnotations in MapKit causing iPhone app to crash

Tags: iphone, mapkit

So my app uses MapKit, and many of the people who have downloaded my app are complaining that it crashes right after the map loads.  I can assume that its crashing once the annotations are being displayed on the map.  I have no history of crashes in my itunes connect crash logs (should i??), but they posted in a review that they're using iphone v1, and iOs 3.1.3.  I have never been able to replicate this crash myself, and I think it may be because the lower version supported by the simulator is 3.2.

Does anyone know who I can debug in this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Check multiple annotation at Same Lat log.